# google query, limit, "reference cell"

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a reference cell to inform a Google sheets query limit.

The =QUERY statement I'm trying to use is:

```
=QUERY(mrclean,"SELECT T,U where V='Unique' 
And W='no match' order by U desc limit 10",1)
```

where I want to replace the "...limit 10"" with a specific cell reference (e.g., '"&E3"'). Where E3 is used as an input for the Top N values (e.g., Top 10, Top 15, Top 20, etc.)

When I replace `"... limit 10"` with `"...limit '"&E3"')`, I get this error:

> unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "where" at line 1, column 62. Was expecting
>   one of:  "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ...
>   "format" ... "options" ... "," ...

I'm sure this is a simple syntax problem on my part - Any suggestions on 'how' to get the =QUERY to work using a 'cell referenced' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting spaces in, you appear to have

```
limit ' " & E3 " '
```

which has extra (single?) quotes bad syntax to append the string. I would expect this to work:

```
=QUERY(mrclean,"SELECT T,U where V='Unique' And W='no match' order by U desc limit " & E3 ,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"...limit "&INT(E3)"`

You need to define the cell, providing the limit, as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
=query(datarange,
"
SELECT A
LIMIT "&INT(E3)&"
LABEL A 'ColumnName'
",)
```

This works like a charm. To avoid confusion I've added a little context.